# How do I properly save changes to a .java file in a data analysis script?

Tags: java, csv, jar, data-analysis

I'm using a script to combine 2 .csv files containing data like onset and offset times in frames. There is a .java file that outputs the frame data to seconds for easier analysis. However, there appears to be some rounding issue, and after editing what I think is the problem in .java, none of the changes are reflected upon running the script again.

I've tried writing print statements to appear when running the script and changing the values of some variables, but nothing appeared and the conversion from frames to seconds was not affected. When removing the file from the folder entirely, the program still runs as intended. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Did you recompile the java file? Java doesn't just run from source (usually, it's technically possible nowadays).

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Depends on how your script works. Easiest option is `javac <filename>` then copy over the resulting `.class` file(s). But if your script requires a `.jar` file, it's more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a jar file:

```
javac file.java
java file
```

If your jar file and source code (.java) file are on the same dir you can run following command to compile it.

If you have a Mac :

```
javac -cp .:lib.jar Main.java
```

If you have a windows :

```
javac -cp .;lib.jar Main.java
```

This command will create byte code (.class file) for the specific .java file.
Then executing,

```
java -cp .:external-library.jar Main
```

will execute that script.

Here,

-cp stands for class path which is the path to the .jar file location.

javac stands for java compiler. it compiles the source code to byte code.